# BootstrapCollectionType and prototype Symfony 3.2

Tags: symfony

I got the error :

Neither the property "amount" nor one of the methods "amount()", "getamount()"/"isamount()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

when I try to get the form field using "prototype" in a Form template.

Form Template:

```
{% block proposal_service_widget %}
    {% set prototype_html = '<td>' ~ form_widget(prototype.amount) ~ 
'</td>' %}
```

The Entities are Proposal, Service and ProposalService

For ProposalType I have an option "proposal_service" as true, and the form template is identifying this option.

```
 ->add('services', BootstrapCollectionType::class, [
                'label' => 'Services:',
                'type' => ProposalServiceType::class,
                'proposal_service' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'sub_widget_col' => 10,
                'button_col' => 2,
                'add_button_text' => 'Add Service',
            ]);
```

My question is Why the Form Template is not identifying the "prototype.amount" ????

if I have this field on my ProposalServiceType ??

```
 $builder
            ->add('amount', null, [
                'label' => 'Qty:', 
                'attr' => ['class' => 'amount', 'min' => 1]
            ])
```

Comment: Have you really added the attribute "amount" in your ProposalServiceType? Is there a getAmount method?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ...Dominic.. Yes, I added amount in my ProposalServiceType and I have the getAmount method in my entity ProposalService.php

Comment: Did you try to rename 'amount' to 'Amount' in your builder? I remember something like that happened to me some time ago.

Comment: Yes. I tried.  But I got the same error, now with the "A"mount  =>>>   Neither the property "Amount" nor one of the methods "Amount()", "getAmount()"/"isAmount()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

Comment: Can you show us a code that we can use to replicate? I have an idea.

Comment: Why is it prototype.amount? Is prototype your entity reference?